# How to use SPSecurityTrimmedControl

Tags: sharepoint

I found out about the SPSecurityTrimmedControl and supposedly it allows us to control web content on SharePoint. For example:

```
<SharePoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl runat="server" Permissions="ManageWeb" PermissionContext="CurrentSite">

<p>Not everyone can see this</p>

</SharePoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl>
```

My question is, where can this be used? Can this be used only in SharePoint Designer? I tried inserting this code in a Script Editor web part but it does not seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`SPSecurityTrimmedControl` server side control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.spsecuritytrimmedcontrol.aspx) is not supported to be embedded via `Script Editor` web part, instead you could enclose web part zone ([`WebPartZone`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webpartpages.webpartzone.aspx)) in `SPSecurityTrimmedControl` control (apparently the page that contains web part zone(s) needs to be modified for that purpose):

```
<SharePointWebControls:SPSecurityTrimmedControl ID="stc" runat="server" PermissionsString="AddListItems">
    <WebPartPages:WebPartZone ID="Right" runat="server">
        <ZoneTemplate>
        </ZoneTemplate>
    </WebPartPages:WebPartZone>
</SharePointWebControls:SPSecurityTrimmedControl>
```

From another hand you could consider to utilize [Target Audiences](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Target-content-to-specific-audiences-33d84cb6-14ed-4e53-a426-74c38ea32293) *to target web part to specific audiences*:

Go to `Edit page -> edit Web Part -> Target Audiences under Advanced group`

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I just found out that SPSecurityTrimmedControl only works for master pages.